# Supervisor who does not answer

Tags: masters, advisor, administration

My advisor has not replied to my email for 4 days. I'm in a hurry, this is a piece of paper that he should sign for me before December 18 what to do? any exemple of emails ? please help!!!

---

Finally, I sent him an email with the subject "urgent" and it worked, he replied almost instantly.

Comment: Perhaps your supervisor has other important things to do which have a higher priority for him at the moment.

Comment: December 18 is three days from now. Has your supervisor previously acknowledged this deadline? If so, just remind them the day before. They may have even more urgent business to attend and may be triaging.

Comment: Also, whatever you do, do not send emails in the way that you have written this question. The breathless tone, excessive punctuation, and lack of capitalization is not suitable for professional communication.

Comment: 4 working days? Or were you expecting an e-mail over the weekend?

Answer (score 9):

Go see him. Failing that, go see the department office. They can intercede for you if he isn't responding. Actually four days isn't so much time in a busy season. And he may not realize your urgency.

Email is not your friend here. Especially if your advisor is a generation or two older than you.

Comment: Telephone is another useful technology.